Can I attach a 12 + 16 pin Mac SSD to an NVMe adaptor, and put that inside a USB enclosure?
I have an SSD drive from an old MacBook Air (A1465) and want to attach it to a 12 + 16 pin to NVMe adaptor, and put that inside a USB enclosure for use as an external hard drive, and to recover the data from it.
But the advertisement for the adaptor says that it is not compatible with housing in an NVMe-to-USB enclosure, that it will only work being slotting directly into the laptop.
https://amzn.eu/d/i4ktVuL
Is the advert correct? Is it just that specific adaptor or is this universally true?
As an alternative to simply recover the data could I get a 12 + 16 pin to SATA adaptor and put it into my SATA hard drive cradle or would there be the same issue here?

Link doesn’t work. Can you provide the product in the US store instead or even better specifications on the device you want to purchase

Probably it isn't an NVMe drive anyway? (i.e., the adapter merely adapts this PCIe drive that "talks" some Apple protocol / command set to an M.2 socket "wiring-wise".) (As per @JoepvanSteen's link, apparently they are PCIe AHCI drives.)


Is the advert correct? Is it just that specific adaptor or is this universally true?

I don't know if 12 + 16 pin implies PCIe AHCI (Note: NOT the same thing as M.2 SATA), but it seems that at least some of the drives with such connector are that.
And I doubt that there are adapter out there that would have a NVMe-AHCI bridge. I mean, unlike USB-NVMe or USB-SATA bridges, probably no vendor has ever produced such bridge chip anyway.
It does seem that there are USB-AHCI bridges though (as per the enclosure suggested by @JoepvanSteen), and it probably makes more sense for you to use an USB enclosure that consists of such a bridge anyway (since double layers of translation like AHCI-NVMe-USB/SCSI is obviously less ideal, if that could even be a thing).

could I get a 12 + 16 pin to SATA adaptor

I highly doubt that such adapter exists, because that would mean to adapt an AHCI controller as a SATA drive to another AHCI controller (the one on your mainboard or some SATA HBA card).

I am an idiot. I realised it probably just says that because the adapter wouldn't physically fit inside the enclosure.

I would have gotten an enclosure as Joe Van Steen suggested, but they are v expensive and my friend has a budget.
I see what you are saying about how it would be slow with the two layers of translation, but would my other cheap (and slow) alternatives be to take my SSD + adaptor as above and either:
-plug them into another adaptor (NVMe M key to USB)
-plug it into an M2 drive docking station/cradle
Should these solutions work hypothetically, though perform slowly?

Lol, sorry, first I hit return, expecting a return character. Then I type it in another app and paste and it removes the return characters. I am obviously new here...

-plug them into another adaptor (NVMe M key to USB) -plug it into an M2 drive docking station/cradle Not really sure what you mean. What's M2 drive docking station/cradle? I realised it probably just says that because the adapter wouldn't physically fit inside the enclosure. And probably no. As I said, your drive is at least possibly not an NVMe drive, but a PCIe AHCI drive, and USB-NVMe enclosure does not work for them, since we are talking about a different command set / protocol here.

@Scott I mean, I get that by docking station/cradle you were probably referring to a "cover-less" enclosure, but then it would also be a USB-(M.2)NVMe adapter, and another adaptor (NVMe M key to USB) makes no sense. There's a kind of ensloure (or cradle) that may work -- a thunderbolt m.2 one that attaches the drive to the host as a PCIe device (as opposed to a USB/SCSI device), but they are not gonna be cheaper than what Joep has suggested, and requires the host port to be a TB port working in TB mode. No USB, that is, at least not USB without PCIe tunneling whatsoever.

@Scott If the problem is that the host machine does not have M.2 PCIe/NVMe slot, but it does have spare regular PCIe slot, you can get something like this. And it doesn't really matter whether you care about the performance. What I meant was, neither USB-AHCI nor NVMe-AHCI bridge chip would be common, if exists at all, because there haven't been new PCIe AHCI drive for years, and "solutions" are doomed to be (relatively) expensive when the market is "niche".
